# VB.Net: Error "System.IO.IOException" comes at runtime

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

The error of "System.IO.IOException" is coming at run time.

The error message which appear is as follows:

System.IO.IOException: The Parameter is incorrect.

```
at Sysytem>IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.BeginWriteCore(Byte[]array, Int32 offset, Int32 numbytes, AsyncCallback userCallback, Object stateObject)
at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Write(Byte[]array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Int32 timeout)
at System.IO.Ports.Serialport.Write(String text)
at WindowsApplication1.Form1.Button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Nikunj\data5\WindowsApplication1\Neuation.vb:Line 151
```

Now the line 151 is: SerialPort1.Write("2)" & vbCrLf)

This is my whole code:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load( _
       ByVal sender As System.Object, _
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
       Handles MyBase.Load

    For i As Integer = 0 To _
       My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.Count - 1
        cbbCOMPorts.Items.Add( _
           My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames(i))
    Next
    Button7.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub
' Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged

'End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'While Button1.Enabled = True
    If IsNumeric(Button1) = False Then
        If NumericUpDown1.Value < 20000 Then
            NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value + 10
            TextBox1.Text = NumericUpDown1.Value
            'If ProgressBar1.Value < 175 Then
            'ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 4
            'End If
        End If
    End If
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button1.Enabled = True
    'End While
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged



End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If IsNumeric(Button2) = False Then
        If NumericUpDown1.Value > 10 Then
            NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value - 10
            'TextBox1.Text = "RCF"
            'If ProgressBar1.Value < 175 Then
            'ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value - 4
            'End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub



' Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
'    Try

'SerialPort1.Write("2&" & RichTextBox2.Text & vbCrLf)
'       If NumericUpDown1.Value < 100 Then
'          SerialPort1.Write("2&000" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)
'     End If
'    If NumericUpDown1.Value < 1000 Then
'       SerialPort1.Write("2&00" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)
'  End If
'        If NumericUpDown1.Value < 10000 Then
'           SerialPort1.Write("2&0" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)
'      End If
'     If NumericUpDown1.Value > 9999 Then
'        SerialPort1.Write("2&" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)
'   End If
' SerialPort1.Write("2&" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)

'        With RichTextBox1
'           .SelectionColor = Color.Black
'.AppendText(RichTextBox2.Text & vbCrLf)
'          .ScrollToCaret()
'     End With
'    RichTextBox2.Text = String.Empty
' Catch ex As Exception
'    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
' End Try
' End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)



End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox2.TextChanged

End Sub
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
    End If
    Try
        With SerialPort1
            .PortName = cbbCOMPorts.Text
            .BaudRate = 19200
            .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            .DataBits = 8
            .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
            '.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
        End With
        SerialPort1.Open()
        RichTextBox2.Text = cbbCOMPorts.Text & " connected."
        Button4.Enabled = False
        Button7.Enabled = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DataReceived( _
   ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
   Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived

    ' RichTextBox1.Invoke(New _
    '  myDelegate(AddressOf updateTextBox), _
    '   New Object() {})
End Sub


Public Delegate Sub myDelegate()
Public Sub updateTextBox()
    'With RichTextBox1
    '.Font = New Font("Garamond", 12.0!, FontStyle.Bold)
    '.SelectionColor = Color.Red
    ' .AppendText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting)
    '.ScrollToCaret()

    'End With

End Sub
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        If NumericUpDown1.Value < 100 Then
            SerialPort1.Write("2&000" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)
        End If
        If NumericUpDown1.Value < 1000 Then
            SerialPort1.Write("2&00" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)
        End If
        If NumericUpDown1.Value < 10000 Then
            SerialPort1.Write("2&0" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)
        End If
        If NumericUpDown1.Value > 9999 Then
            SerialPort1.Write("2&" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)
        End If
        ' SerialPort1.Write("2&" & NumericUpDown1.Value & vbCrLf)
        SerialPort1.Write("2)" & vbCrLf)
        'With RichTextBox1
        ' .SelectionColor = Color.Black
        '.AppendText(RichTextBox2.Text & vbCrLf)
        ' .ScrollToCaret()
        'End With
        RichTextBox2.Text = cbbCOMPorts.Text & " connected."
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    ' SerialPort1.Write("2)" & vbCrLf)
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Button3.Enabled = False
    Button6.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    SerialPort1.Write("2*" & vbCrLf)
    Button3.Enabled = True
    Button6.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Try
        SerialPort1.Close()
        RichTextBox2.Text = SerialPort1.PortName & " disconnected."
        Button4.Enabled = True
        Button7.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Button3.Enabled = True
        Button6.Enabled = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub cbbCOMPorts_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbbCOMPorts.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If NumericUpDown3.Value > 0 Then
        NumericUpDown3.Value = NumericUpDown3.Value - 1
        If NumericUpDown3.Value = 0 Then
            ' If NumericUpDown2.Value > 0 Then
            'NumericUpDown2.Value = NumericUpDown2.Value - 1
            'If NumericUpDown2.Value >= 0 And NumericUpDown3.Value = 0 Then
            ' NumericUpDown3.Value = 59

            'End If
            'End If
        End If
    Else 'NumericUpDown3.Value = 59
        If NumericUpDown2.Value > 0 Then
            NumericUpDown2.Value = NumericUpDown2.Value - 1
            If NumericUpDown2.Value >= 0 And NumericUpDown3.Value = 0 Then
                NumericUpDown3.Value = 59

            End If
        End If
    End If



    If NumericUpDown3.Value = 0 And NumericUpDown2.Value = 0 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        SerialPort1.Write("2*" & vbCrLf)
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Button3.Enabled = True
        Button6.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NumericUpDown2_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown2.ValueChanged

End Sub

Private Sub NumericUpDown3_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown3.ValueChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Display_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles Display.LinkClicked


End Sub


Private Sub ContextMenuStrip1_Opening(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged

End Sub
```

End Class

Another thing, this error comes only when i try to run the application in windows XP. It work without any error in Windows 7.

Please help me how to resolve the Exception error. I thing error is related to serial port1. It is not able to transmit data.

The application is to run the motor. It easily get connect to COM Port but when i click on START Button the application gets stop and the above error message is shown.

Please Help me to resolve the issue. Thank in advance.

Comment: Unless you post your code also, we can't really help you.

Comment: I have added the whole code. Have a look.

Comment: It is a low-level error, it comes from the device driver.  Which are certainly not created equal, especially the drivers for USB emulators are often very flaky.  Doing something unwise like disconnecting the USB cable while the port is opened is also a very good way to get the driver into a bad state.  If you can't find a driver update then throw away the USB emulator and find another one from a different manufacturer.

Comment: Thank You @HansPassant. You helped me to fix the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant But Sir my software started working when i update my windows XP service pack 2 to service pack 3. But Sir, is there any possible way through which i can run my software in windows service pack 2??

Comment: Please up Option Strict On at the top of your code or in your project properties.